# Dúvida random.shuffle() , retorna None(dentro do print)

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

Porque quando `random.shuffle()` usado dentro da string retorna `None`?

Descobri depois que da pra usar `shuffle` se tirar do `print` e colocar em uma linha única mas não entendi o porque dele travar.

Código exemplo

```
from random import shuffle

n1= str (input ('Digite o nome do primeiro aluno: '))
n2= str (input ('Digite o nome do segundo alino: '))
n3= str (input ('Digite o nome do terceiro aluno '))
n4= str (input ('Digite o nome do quarto aluno: '))
l= [n1,n2,n3,n4]

print ('A ordem dos trabalhos será: {}' .format(shuffle (l) ))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pela [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) vê que `random.shuffle` embaralha a lista em si e não devolve nenhum valor:

> (..) Shuffle the sequence x in place. (...)

Partindo de um exemplo concreto de lista de notas:

```
l = [15,2,20,12]
```

Se fizer:

```
shuffle(l)
```

Está a embaralhar a lista. E dependendo de como foi baralhada ela poderia ficar assim:

```
>>> l
[2, 15, 12, 20]
```

A função no entanto não devolve nenhum valor nem nenhuma nova lista baralhada, ela apenas altera a lista recebida por parâmetro. Por isso não fará sentido fazer:

```
.format(shuffle (l) )
```

A solução para o seu código é exatamente como tinha mencionado:

```
from random import shuffle

n1= str (input ('Digite o nome do primeiro aluno: '))
n2= str (input ('Digite o nome do segundo alino: '))
n3= str (input ('Digite o nome do terceiro aluno '))
n4= str (input ('Digite o nome do quarto aluno: '))
l= [n1,n2,n3,n4]
shuffle (l) # só shuffle

print ('A ordem dos trabalhos será: {}' .format(l)) # só mostrar
```

É possível até ver a implementação da função `shuffle` consultando o seu [código fonte](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/132a7d7cdbc7cb89fa1c1f4e8192241c3d68f549/Lib/random.py#LC262):

```
def shuffle(self, x, random=None):
    """Shuffle list x in place, and return None.
    Optional argument random is a 0-argument function returning a
    random float in [0.0, 1.0); if it is the default None, the
    standard random.random will be used.
    """

    if random is None:
        randbelow = self._randbelow
        for i in reversed(range(1, len(x))):
            # pick an element in x[:i+1] with which to exchange x[i]
            j = randbelow(i+1)
            x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
    else:
        _int = int
        for i in reversed(range(1, len(x))):
            # pick an element in x[:i+1] with which to exchange x[i]
            j = _int(random() * (i+1))
            x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
```

Repare como em nenhum lugar desta função é feito um `return`.

Atente no comentário feito no inicio da função:

> """Shuffle list x in place, and return None.

Answer (score 1):

Estava com a mesma dúvida. Só precisei passar a variável `l` como parâmetro antes de 'printar'.

```
from random import shuffle
l = ['n1', 'n2', 'n3', 'n4']
shuffle(l)
print(l)

[n1, n4, n3, n2]
```